# How to monitor a HTTP POST request?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, http, post

I am trying to determine how a third party website is issuing HTTP POST requests. The base URL is as follows `http://www.example.com/search`. I would like to put together the body of an HTTP POST request from an iPhone app using objective-c. Is there an extension that I can install in FireFox or Chrome or Safari, such that after I type something in their search box and press enter, I can monitor the details of the HTTP POST request that is sent from my browser to their servers?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I use Fiddler, works great for me, and very simple/straight forward. Doesn't need any configuration.

http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/

Comment: This is only for Windows correct?  Is there a Mac OSX or Linux equivalent?

Answer (score 1):

personally I use OWSAP ZAP. Has nice features in it like being able to modify HTTP headers and replay / resend etc. Also has penetration testing features too.

It works by setting up a local proxy on your machine and therefore all HTTP / HTTPS requests you make from any web browser are intercepted by it.

https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Zed_Attack_Proxy_Project

Answer (score 0):

You could always use the good old Wireshark, there are some other apps with nicer UI, but Wireshark it's Free!

For chrome there is various extension, I like to use Rest Console: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cokgbflfommojglbmbpenpphppikmonn

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong but this Rest Console only sends POST requests.  It doesn't allow monitoring of POST requests originating in the browsers own sessions.